# How to increase the list size on button click on lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, array

Below is my code .please do let me know how to increase the size of the list on my component on button click?
Right now it is replacing the previous value . I want to add the new value to the existing array.

```
Component :-
     <lightning:layout >
                 <aura:iteration items="{!v.ArrLst}" var="item">
            <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small">
                   {!item.id}
           </lightning:layoutItem>

            <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small">
                   {!item.Name}
           </lightning:layoutItem>
               </aura:iteration>

      </lightning:layout>
                <lightning:input aura:id="inpId" value=""/>
                <lightning:button label="Add" onclick="{!c.addIt}"/>

Controller :-
    addIt : function(component, event, helper) {
        var arrTsk=[];
        arrTsk.push({id:'123',Name:component.find('inpId').get("v.value")});
        alert(JSON.stringify(arrTsk));
        component.set("v.ArrLst",arrTsk);             
      }
```

Comment: I think every time you call addit function it reset the array - var arrTsk=[]; 
so decalare this outside this addit function and try again

Comment: @sahil-- i think ur logic is correct but synatx wise its not working. like if i put this outiside js is not getting saved.

Comment: i declared in aura init handler ,its getting saved but then on button click its getting error that arrTsk not declared something

Comment: Could you please show me the controller code?

Comment: {    doInit :function(component, event, helper) {
            var arrTsk=[];

        },

Comment: rest is same inside that method

Comment: again this code is replacing the old value

Comment: we need to declare that array globally i think and fetch it inside the second method

Comment: I have updated my answer below please check and its working as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `arrTsk` array is within the scope of your  `addIt` function and will get declared every time `addIt`  is called, if you want it to persist it needs to be outside:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="arrTsk" type="string[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="ArrLst" type="string[]"/>
     <lightning:layout >
                 <aura:iteration items="{!v.ArrLst}" var="item">
            <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small">
                   {!item.id}
           </lightning:layoutItem>

            <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small">
                   {!item.Name}
           </lightning:layoutItem>
               </aura:iteration>

      </lightning:layout>
                <lightning:input aura:id="inpId" value=""/>
                <lightning:button label="Add" onclick="{!c.addIt}"/>
</aura:component>
```

JS

```
({
   addIt : function(component, event, helper) { 
        var a = component.get('v.arrTsk');
        a.push({id:'123',Name:component.find('inpId').get("v.value")});
        console.log('arrtskelse'+JSON.stringify(a));
        component.set("v.ArrLst",a); 
    }
})
```

Comment: thnx Mr. Genius...it worked like magic, was stuck in that since very long.